# How do you find the number of vertices on a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A graph with 21 edges has seven vertices of degree 1, three of degree 2, seven of degree 3 and the rest of degree 4. How many vertices does it have?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) may help. I'm not sure though.

Comment: [Oh, now I see where you got it from!](https://www.google.com/#q=A+graph+with+21+edges+has+seven+vertices+of+degree+1%2C+three+of+degree+2%2C+seven+of+degree+3+and+the+rest+of+degree+4.+How+many+vertices+does+it+have%3F)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges, so just solve for $x$,
$$7\cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 2 + 7 \cdot 3 + x \cdot 4 = 2 \cdot 21$$

Then $7 + 3 + 7 + x$ is the number of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that it has $n$ vertices of degree $4$; then the sum of the degrees is $$7+3\cdot2+7\cdot3+4n=4n+34\;.$$ On the other hand, you know that the sum of the degrees of the vertices is twice the number of edges, so ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Sum of degrees is equal to 2times the number of edges.
So we are given the edges as 21 therefore 21*2=42.
So we just solve for y 
7*1+3*2+7*3+y*4 = 42
Solving for y=
4x= 42-34
Y=2
Therefore 2 is the number of vertices of degree 4